# Elasticsearch: How to boost documents on how early the keywords matches the text?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, elastic-stack, boosting

I wanted to understand how it is possible to boost documents in full text searching  on how early the keyword is found the requested field.

Example:

Document 1 (Message Field): Joe and Sarah went to the store.

Document 2 (Message Field): Sarah and Joe are going swimming.

And when I search for documents with Joe in the message field, I want Document 1 to scored more, because the match is boosted as it catches Joe early in Document 1 than Document 2.

Thanks.